# Android opengles glBindTexture() calls

Tags: android, opengl-es

My game already consists of an atlas the size of 1024x1024 as I am aware that is the max size for a texture. The problem is I need about 1-2 more of these 1024x1024 textures. That should give me 3 glBindTexture() calls which I know is huge performance drag. I have not tested it yet because I am having other problems currently but would this slow my application by a considerable amount? Is there another solution?

Comment: I don't think THREE `glBindTexture` will be a HUGE performance drag. At least not in a range where you should worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about any performance loss, I'd recommend you to profile your application so you really can see where your application's bottleneck is, and then come back if it turns out to be horrible.

Three big atlas textures are still better than many small textures that you bind over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Currently my game has around 6 512x512 texture atlases and I still dont require any loading screens on any phone so far. Although if you are going to do a lot of binding you may want to look into making a Batcher class that will submit all of your vertices to the GPU at one, it will speed up your application considerably

Comment: I do currently use a batcher where i draw (add) all the vertices then do a final call to glDrawArray/Elements. So far it this has had the biggest impact on performance since I don't require too many draw calls.

Comment: It shouldnt impact your performance even if it is for a small number of draw calls, it may slightly but after time it is good to have one